# Silverlight: pause animation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a control that supports some animation.

I haven't any access to its inner structure.

How can I get screenshots of this animation every 200 milliseconds?

---

I've tried with this code:

```
    var timer = new Timer(state =>
            {
                this.root.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                            var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.root, new TranslateTransform());
                            SaveImageSomewhere(bitmap, "picture_" + (i++) + ".png");
                    });
            }, null, 0, 200);
```

But it doesn't fire screenshots action with 200ms intervals because capturing invokes in UI thread.

Is there any possibility to stop (freeze) animation for some control?

Comment: Are you able to edit the control template using Blend?

Comment: @jv42 Able, but it looks like animation in this control is being attached from the code. It's quite complex control.

Comment: So it's not controlled by the VSM?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest downloading [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/) and use that to look at the control and how it is doing the animation. If it is using a Storyboard then you will be able to navigate the control tree to get at the Storyboard and you could call the [Pause method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190455%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on it.

Another option would be to host the UI inside of a browser control in a C# win form or WPF app and just use that to capture the screenshots (or [download a pre-built one](http://nolovelust.com/post/C-Website-Screenshot-Generator-AKA-Get-Screenshot-of-Webpage-With-Aspnet-C.aspx)).